# Technology stack for WebDav/SFTP frontend to a web-based file manager

Tags: library, programming

Using the words of this SE answer https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/260919/45826 I am designing a [zero-based](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/zero-based-thinking-ZBT), [greenfield](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenfield_project), [clean sheet of paper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean-sheet_review) solution to the following problem.

## The problem

Create a frontend (or call it a proxy, if you will) to access a web-based file manager by a standardized over the network file access protocol like WebDAV or SFTP.

The frontend will have to

1. screen scrape the file manager website to get file listings, upload and download files
2. accept WebDAV/SFTP/FTP (pick one) connections and translate the client requests to operations performed upon the file manager website

### Web-based file manager

It is a plain web-based file manager. The picture bellow is just to give a rough idea. There is no other way to access the files except through the web-based file manager.

[image: http://www.mollify.org/]

### Protocol

I went through https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_transfer_protocols and decided the protocol could be either WebDAV, SFTP or possibly FTP.

## Goal

Use a programming language that is best suited for the task. That is, screen scraping and writing network server for one of the protocols. Best suited in the sense that it requires least programming work to accomplish the task. That in turn probably mostly depends on available libraries available in the language.

## Question

What programming language will be well suited for the task? Why? (What libraries or important language features does it provide?)

Comment: Please note that asking for "what programming language shall I use" is outside the scope of this site. Asking for specific libraries fits here, but then you'd have to name the programming language they should match.